# Laravel Not Inserting Json Data Into MySQL

Tags: php, laravel

Please see the code below, can't figure out what is wrong but insert is not happening... any ideas on how to debug/fix

**Laravel - Controller**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\PhoneContactsPhonesModel;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CreatePhoneContactsController extends Controller
{
    public function create(Request $request, $id)
    {

        $users = new PhoneContactsPhonesModel;
        $json = dd(json_decode($request->getContent(), true));

        foreach ($json as $key => $value) {

            $users->mysql_user_id = $id;
            $users->phone = $key;
            $users->name = $value;
            $users->save();

        }

    }
}
```

**Laravel - Route**

```
Route::post('create_phone_contacts/{id}', 'CreatePhoneContactsController@create');
```

Something is wrong with foreach loop - it seems to be working well with hardcoded values outside the loop

Comment: what error is showing?

Comment: in postman there is no error.. just giving back the array

Comment: You're using `dd()`. That function will dump the value and terminate the execution of the script, so the foreach loop will never be executed..

Comment: ok removing dd just inserts only 1 row - which is the last row

Comment: That's because you're just updating and saving the same object over and over on each iteration. Are you trying to update existing users or create new ones?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i feel stupid after your responses :)... your answer is correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove dd() and create object in for loop. This will solve your issue.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Models\PhoneContactsPhonesModel;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CreatePhoneContactsController extends Controller
{
    public function create(Request $request, $id)
    {  
        $json = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
        foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
            $users = new PhoneContactsPhonesModel;// ---> here
            $users->mysql_user_id = $id;
            $users->phone = $key;
            $users->name = $value;
            $users->save();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*All you have to do is, remove dd() from your code.*

**Change this**

```
$json = dd(json_decode($request->getContent(), true));  //change here
```

**To this**

```
$json = json_decode($request->getContent(), true); //change this remove dd()
```

It'll work..